# bootstrap popover showing outside div area

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap popover and it works fine however when I hover outside the area of div the popup comes up. If I change the div to button then this doesn't happen. Help?

Here is a  [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7Emjp/1/) , if you hover outside the red div area the popover shows too.

css

```
.test {
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:red;
}
```

html

```
 <a title="some title" class="infopop" rel="popover" data-content="some content"><div class="test">Hover over me!</div></a>
```

js

```
$('.infopop').popover({
html: true,
trigger: 'manual',
container: $(this).attr('id'),
placement: 'right',
content: function () {
    $return = '<div class="hover-hovercard"></div>';
}
}).on("mouseenter", function () {
var _this = this;
$(this).popover("show");
$(this).siblings(".popover").on("mouseleave", function () {
    $(_this).popover('hide');
});
}).on("mouseleave", function () {
var _this = this;
setTimeout(function () {
    if (!$(".popover:hover").length) {
        $(_this).popover("hide")
    }
}, 100);
});
```

Comment: Does the _jsfiddle_ work for you on your side? You may need to clarify your question a bit, as well... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a display property of "inline-block" to the test class. That should limit the hover coverage to 100 x 100 pixels.

```
.test {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:Red;
    overflow:hidden;
    display: inline-block;
  }
```